# How to get thumbnail for 3D Model programmatically

Tags: php, 3d, thumbnails

My problem is about `3D Model files`. In my project, I want to thumbnail of uploaded 3D model files in system. Background of system is PHP. Is there a library / way about subject?

E.g formats: `.obj`, `.stl`, `.gcode`

Comment: you can download on you server 3d model, but render this file you need on frontend by javascript using WebGL for example.

Comment: You need to use come program to create the image first. Check this out: http://www.assimp.org/

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

If the client side is yours too, and you are rendering your models before uploading, you can write a simple JavaScript script to convert the canvas into an image. Then you can upload this image using a simple php script through an AJAX call. There should be some seconds of timeout to let the canvas render properly. 
I have even found a code sample for this [here](https://forum.sketchfab.com/t/generate-thumbnails/1616/2).